# Replace involving original string

Tags: python, string, replace

I am trying to replace some text with something else that depends on the original text in Python3. For example, say I have `"[[procedural programming|procedural programming languages]]"`, I need to replace that with the later text, so just `procedural programming languages`.

In general, I need a function which takes a string and a function and applies the function to the string and then replaces it. For example, reversing a string could be done like so:

```
text = "123456 123456 84708467 11235"
new_text = special_replace(text, lambda x: x[::-1])

>>> 654321 654321 84708467 11235
```

Or the previous example:

```
text = "[[procedural programming|procedural programming languages]] [meow|woof]"
new_text = specail_replace(text, lambda x: x.replace("[[", "").replace("]]","").split("|")[1])

>>> procedural programming languages [meow|woof]
```

Comment: I don't understand what your `special_replace` does that is different to the function you are passing in. Why not just call the lambda?

Comment: I just realised in the example given that it isn't really clear at all. Adding an edit.

Comment: I think you should get acquainted with `re.sub` function (and with regexps in general).

Comment: +Chris_Rands The example shows why, but I'll explain it here: If I was to do `new_text = text[::-1]` like you suggested, it would reverse the entire string. I only want sub-strings that match `123456` to be reversed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a regular expression and use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) with group reference to replace them:

```
>>> text = "[[procedural programming|procedural programming languages]] [meow|woof]"
>>> p = r"\[\[.*?\|(.*?)\]\]"
>>> re.findall(p, text)
['procedural programming languages']
>>> re.sub(p, r"\1", text)
'procedural programming languages [meow|woof]'
```

Note that `[`, `|`, and `]` all have to be escaped. Here `(.*?)` is a capturing group for the second term, and `\1` references that group in the replacement string.

For more complex stuff, like also reversing the group, you can use a callback function:

```
>>> re.sub(p, lambda m: m.group(1)[::-1], text)
'segaugnal gnimmargorp larudecorp [meow|woof]'
```

Comment: Thanks, just what  I needed!